# i am trying to convert characters in a string from capital letter to small letter using for loop.it's not converting into small letter in output

Tags: c, function

i cannot find any error in the code

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

    char a[50];
    int i;

    setbuf(stdout,NULL);

    printf("enter a string");

    gets(a);

    for(i=0;a[i]<='\0';i++){
        if(a[i]>='A'&&a[i]<='Z'){
            a[i]=a[i]+32;
        }
    }

    printf("%s",a);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

output

enter a string SDJnjj
SDJnjj

Comment: `a[i]=a[i]+32;` There is a standard function `tolower()` declared in `ctypes.h` that can be used without using magic numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your whole `for` loop is skipped, character `'\0'` is zero, any printable string you enter won't have characters less than zero.  Instead, change the condition to `!=`:

```
for(i=0; a[i]!='\0'; i++){ ... }
```

or simply `a[i]` since 0 evaluates to `false` in C

```
for(i=0; a[i]; i++){ ... }
```

Also, [*never* use `gets`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used), it creates a security vulnerability for buffer overflows, use [`fgets`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3p.html) instead.

Furthermore, there's already a function that does this for you called [`tolower`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/toupper.3.html).  It is the preferred method if you're allowed to use it:

```c
#include <ctype.h>
...

for(i=0;a[i];i++){
    a[i]=tolower(a[i]);
}
```